# Chart.js import not working when building app

Tags: chart.js, node-modules, svelte, vite, sveltekit

> my-app/node_modules/chart.js/auto' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /my-app/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/about.svelte.js
>
> Did you mean to import chart.js/auto/auto.js? 500

Im trying to run vite dev and when using chart.js its giving me this error message, not sure what do (note: im using the svelte plugin with vite since this is a svelte app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a .d.ts file with `declare module 'chart.js/auto/auto';` and then instead of importing from `chart.js/auto` you import from `'chart.js/auto/auto';`